# How could I show the info of a mentioned user inside of this embed? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want this code to be something where you can mention someone and get their tag, createdAt, and id, but still keep it to where if you don't mention someone, it just shows your tag, createdAt, and id.

How would I do this?

```
else if (message.content === `${prefix}user`) {
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('User Information')
    .addField('Username', message.author.tag)
    .addField('Join Date', message.author.createdAt)
    .addField('User ID', message.author.id)
    .setColor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("this is a footer")
    message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, in your current code, what you do is show the information of the author of the message. And what you want to do is to be able to show the info of a user who has been mentioned in the content of the message, when a mention is there.

Alright! First, know that a discord mention is of the following form:
`<@!012345678901234567>`, where the bunch of numbers is the ID of the user you have mentioned.

I presume your command would either look one of two ways:

- `${prefix}user`
- `${prefix}user <mention>`

Thus, instead of checking the exact value of the message, check the beginning of the content, and then if there is a remaining argument.

Also, if you mention someone, you have to fetch the user to be able to get their information. You can do that using the discord guild you're in.

Here is an example code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWidth(`${prefix}user`)) {
    // We create a 'user' which will either be
    // the author of the message or the mention
    let user = message.author
    // get rid of the command name to leave the mention if there is one
    const mention = message.content.slice(`${prefix}user `.length)
    
    // A simple test using regex to see if a mention is there
    if (/^<@!\d+>$/.test(mention)) {
        // get the actual id
        const userId = mention.slice(3, mention.length - 1)
        // fetch the user from the guild you're in.
        // Make sure to have MY_GUILD defined somewhere.
        // Or you can use 'message.guild' directly.
        // Also make sure to do that in an async function
        // for the await keyword to work.
        user = (await MY_GUILD.members.fetch(userId)).user
    
    // replace 'message.author' by our defined 'user' variable
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('User Information')
    .addField('Username', user.tag)
    .addField('Join Date', user.createdAt)
    .addField('User ID', user.id)
    .setColor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff) + 1)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("this is the footer of my answer")
    message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

---

## Edit

As you asked, here is more info on MY_GUILD and async functions.

Basically, a guild in `discord.js` represents your discord server. In your code, for example, you can access the guild of the message you have by writing `message.guild`. But you can also get the guild you want by doing

```js
bot.guilds.fetch('<id of the guild here>')
```

where `bot` is the discord client that you have defined.

Finally, you can know how to get any object you want from `discord.js` by [checking the discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

**Now what's an async function?**

In Javascript, you can execute functions asynchronously.
If you have those instructions:

```js
doSomething(); // takes 2 seconds
doSomethingElse(); // takes 3 seconds
console.log("hello");
```

If the functions `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` are synchronous, they will block your code. You will wait 2 seconds for `doSomething` to finish, then 3 more seconds for `doSomethingElse` to finish, and then finally `console.log("hello");` will print.

If they are asynchronous however, they will run in parallel to your code. Thus, `console.log("hello");` will execute instantly, then you will wait 2 seconds for `doSomething` to finish, and then only 1 more second for `doSomethingElse` to finish since it was already running in parallel.

All of this involves the use of `Promise` objects. I recommend Fireship's short videos on the subject:

- [Javascript Promise in 100 Seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4)
- [The Async Await Episode I Promised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn3tm0quoqE)

Comment: How would I define MY_GUILD? Would it be some sort of id?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite familiar with async functions, could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Hold on, let me modify the answer to explain async functions. @JujuT
As for MY_GUILD, I explained it in the comments just above it but I can give more details.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Where and how would I put the async function inside of my code? I'm still sort of starting with this stuff, so you're really helping me out here. :-)

Comment: See the function where you put your `if (message.content...)` statement? You probably got that from an event listener:
`bot.on('message', function (message) { ... })`

The function in there is what you want to turn into an async one. So you write:
`bot.on('message', async function (message) { ... })`

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks! I'll make sure to try this out.